# Can 2nd floor addition handle drywall and other finishes?

Tags: finishing, addition

I bought a home about a year ago which was originally a simple one-floor 2 bed/1 bath setup. At some point many years ago a prior owner built out the second floor to add two more rooms and a full bathroom.

They finished it by using drop ceiling with fiberglass insulation batts between that and the cold attic space open to elements via the gable, wood paneling, and quarter round which certainly left a good amount of gaps throughout, etc.

Makes we wonder--did they finish cheaply because it was of course cheaper to do so, or was there another reason?

[Images](https://imgur.com/a/N79ELN9)

Now to my question. I would love to bring it up to date and change over to drywall for both the ceiling and walls, etc. so that its warmer/cooler during the respective months and overall just looks better, but was unsure if there was anything I needed to check to ensure the additional load of drywall and updated finishes could be supported. I do plan to have an inspector take a look but figured I'd check with fellow netizens as well.

Thanks for any guidance

Comment: There is an important issue of access to electrical, plumbing, etc. For electrical, any junction boxes need to always be accessible. For plumbing, any valves need to be accessible. There may be nothing except the light fixture, which can be replaced with a box and fixture accessible from the room, but you may find lots of other stuff above the drop ceiling, perhaps predating the finishing of the room.

Comment: Most DIYers like to think they can do master finish work.  Most times they are not masters(me included).  The main thing was the second floor done right.  Usually there is more than just slapping some walls up.

Comment: Looks like they didn't do a good job of installing the insulation (draping them _over_ the joists is an unusual choice and leaves them to sag as you can see). However using fiberglass insulation is far from being "cheap" - it's probably the most common type of insulation installed in the US. Those look like 2x8 rafters, so there's a very good chance that you can hang drywall on them without any issue whatsoever - however, you'd need to measure the span to know for sure. I agree the drop ceiling looks cheap & commercial, but it was probably more $$ than proper drywall.

Comment: Drop ceiling may cost more in parts than drywall. But it is a lot less work than drywall. Or rather, than *finished* drywall. Slapping up drywall so it is secure and functional is trivial. Taping/patching/painting so it looks really good is a lot of work, especially for those who are not very experienced with it (like me).

Comment: What is a "2/1 setup"?

Comment: Yes, by 2/1 I am referring to 2 beds 1 bath. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: [edit] that info into the question so new readers aren't confused.

Comment: so finally had time to get back up there, and another challenge i am going to have is that the joists are not evenly spaced, which explains why they just draped the fiber insulation batts over the top instead of inbetween. Looks like i'll either need to just do blow in or do alot of cutting to get the batts to fill in the space.

Answer (score 1):

You could check whether your rafters were sized for 10 psf dead load or 20 psf dead load from [IRC R802.4.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-8-roof-ceiling-construction#IRC2018_Pt03_Ch08_SecR802.4.1). The spans in these tables are measured along the rafter's horizontal projection, not its length. E.g. a 10 ft rafter oriented at 30 degrees has a span of (10 ft)(cos 30) = 8.7 ft. A single layer of asphalt shingles plus 2x10 rafters plus 1/2" OSB roof sheathing is about 10 psf. 1/2" drywall is about 1.5psf.

Comment: Great, this is super helpful. I'll take a look at this. My post may be confusing/sounds like I am referring to just the ceiling however I am looking to update the walls as well if that matters. Would I use the same table info, or does it differ for floor joists?

Comment: @Rok95, walls aren't very fine grained in the IRC, assuming that this is your code (it probably is). 1 story versus 2 story is the code's level of granularity. If the walls passed inspection, then your drywall's weight isn't interesting. See the table referenced from https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2018_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.3.1 if you're curious. I don't know where your interest in floor joists came from at the end there, but floor joist tables are at https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-5-floors#IRC2018_Pt03_Ch05_SecR502.3.